# Conditional vspace between two sections?

Tags: spacing, sectioning, memoir, conditionals

I'd like to add an additional vertical space between two section headings if they follow each other, i.e., there is no other text or anything else between them. Is there some conditional if command perhaps using something like if@aftersection...?

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter title}
\section{A first section title}
\section{A second section title}
Just some text. There should be a conditional vspace between the first 
section and the second section if there is nothing else between them.

\section{A third section}
Some more text here.

\section{A fourth section}
Some more text.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you have to accommodate for all the possible argument combinations offered by [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir)'s `\section`. Specifically, it takes two optional arguments (for the ToC and the running header). Apart from that, one can scan to see if the next token is `\section` using `\@ifnextchar`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{xparse}

\let\oldsection\section
\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{s o o m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\oldsection*{#4}}
    {\IfValueTF{#2}
      {\IfValueTF{#3}
        {\oldsection[#2][#3]{#4}}
        {\oldsection[#2]{#4}}}
      {\oldsection{#4}}}%
  \@ifnextchar\section{\vspace{5\baselineskip}}{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter title}
\section{A first section title}
\section{A second section title}
Just some text. There should be a conditional \verb|\vspace| between the first 
section and the second section if there is nothing else between them.

\section{A third section}
Some more text here.

\section{A fourth section}
Some more text.

\end{document}
```

---

Here is another option:

Define a macro `\ifnextcommandis{<this>}{<true>}{<next>}` which grabs three arguments. You specify `<this>` and `<true>`, and it is assumed that whatever follows your macro will be the `<next>` macro:

```
\newcommand{\ifnextcommandis}[3]{%
  \def\thiscommand{#1}% Store this command
  \def\nextcommand{#3}% Store next command
  \ifx\nextcommand\thiscommand\relax
    #2%
  \fi
  \nextcommand}% Re-insert next command

\let\oldsection\section
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{s o o m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\oldsection*{#4}}
    {\IfValueTF{#2}
      {\IfValueTF{#3}
        {\oldsection[#2][#3]{#4}}
        {\oldsection[#2]{#4}}}
      {\oldsection{#4}}}%
  \ifnextcommandis{\section}{\vspace{5\baselineskip}}%
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Werner, that works beautifully. Perfect. I'll vote your answer up, when I have votes again ... in some hours.

Comment: Just an additional twist @Werner ;) If I wanted the same to happen between a `\section` and `\subsection`, I guess all I would have to change is the last line, e.g. change  `\@ifnextchar\section{\vspace{5\baselineskip}}{}%` to  `\@ifnextchar\subsection{\vspace{5\baselineskip}}{}%`. Would that also require the two optional statements to accommodate the TOC?

Comment: @Tina: Yes, you can try that. I've also added some more content to the end of my answer with an interface `\ifnextcommandis{<this>}{<true>}{<next>}`.

Comment: Thanks for adding the macro option @Werner. Just wondering, would the using the macro be more efficient, e.g., require less processing, or what would be the advantage of using it?

Comment: @Tina: The macro is probably less efficient. It grabs whatever follows `\section` as an argument and then puts it back into the input stream. However, there is probably little to notice in terms of performance issues. The advantage is a easy-to-use interface.